# What's special about 787?

Tags: haskell, integer-arithmetic

In ghci, using the [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) package:

```
Math.NumberTheory.Powers.General> :set +s
Math.NumberTheory.Powers.General> integerRoot 786 ((10^32)^786)
100000000000000000000000000000000
(0.04 secs, 227,064 bytes)
Math.NumberTheory.Powers.General> integerRoot 787 ((10^32)^787)
```

After five minutes, it still hasn't responded. Why is it taking so long?

(From some ad-hoc testing, it appears to be slow for all choices larger than 787 and fast for all choices smaller.)

Comment: I get a segmentation fault when I run this with the latest arithmoi version and GHCi version 8.0.1 on Mac OS 10.12.5, with the `:set +s` option. Without `:set +s` I get "Bus error: 10". Seems like this `integerRoot` function makes memory act pretty strangely.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

arithmoi [implements `integerRoot`](https://github.com/cartazio/arithmoi/blob/1ef36280b2f4cfa8def4e2f0ba645c55c643e577/Math/NumberTheory/Powers/General.hs#L58) by getting an initial approximate root and refining its guess with Newton’s method. For (10<sup>32</sup>)<sup>786</sup>, the second approximation gets a really good starting point:

```
> appKthRoot 786 ((10^32)^786)
100000000000000005366162204393472
```

For (10<sup>32</sup>)<sup>787</sup>, the second approximation gets a really bad starting point. Like, *really* bad.

```
> appKthRoot 787 ((10^32)^787)   
1797693134862315907729305190789024733617976978942306572734300811577326758055009
6313270847732240753602112011387987139335765878976881441662249284743063947412437
7767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913
110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```

It actually gets this approximation for everything starting there.

```
> length $ nub [appKthRoot x ((10^32)^x) | x <- [787..1000]]
1
```

Anyway, putting in [the important parts of `appKthRoot`](https://github.com/cartazio/arithmoi/blob/1ef36280b2f4cfa8def4e2f0ba645c55c643e577/Math/NumberTheory/Powers/General.hs#L216), we get:

```
> let h = 106; k = 786; n = (10^32)^k; !(I# s) = h * k - k in floor (scaleFloat (h - 1) (fromInteger (n `shiftRInteger` s) ** (1/fromIntegral k) :: Double))
100000000000000005366162204393472

> let h = 106; k = 787; n = (10^32)^k; !(I# s) = h * k - k in floor (scaleFloat (h - 1) (fromInteger (n `shiftRInteger` s) ** (1/fromIntegral k) :: Double))
179769313486231590772930519078902473361797697894230657273430081157732675805500963132708477322407536021120113879871393357658789768814416622492847430639474124377767893424865485276302219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```

and taking a look at what’s going into `scaleFloat`:

```
> let h = 106; k = 786; n = (10^32)^k; !(I# s) = h * k - k in fromInteger (n `shiftRInteger` s) ** (1/fromIntegral k) :: Double
2.465190328815662

> let h = 106; k = 787; n = (10^32)^k; !(I# s) = h * k - k in fromInteger (n `shiftRInteger` s) ** (1/fromIntegral k) :: Double
Infinity
```

Yeah, that’d do it. (10<sup>32</sup>)<sup>786</sup> ÷ 2<sup>82530</sup> ≈ 2<sup>1023.1</sup> fits in a double, but (10<sup>32</sup>)<sup>787</sup> ÷ 2<sup>82635</sup> ≈ 2<sup>1024.4</sup> does not.

Comment: That is frustrating indeed. The whole reason I have these big `Integer`s lying around in the first place (and part of the reason I'm using arithmoi) is because I'm working really hard to avoid `Double`...

Comment: @DanielWagner: Yeah, I’m trying to figure out why they’re not just scaling by more than (h − 1)k. Might have a fix in a little while.

Comment: @DanielWagner: For example, ``let !a@(I# a#) = 1024; h = 106; k = 787; n = (10^32)^k; !(I# s) = h * k - k in floor (scaleFloat 105 (fromInteger (n `shiftRInteger` (s +# a#)) ** (1/fromIntegral k) * 2**(fromIntegral a/k) :: Double))`` results in a reasonable approximation, and you could just keep scaling `a` up as appropriate. Might be worth raising an issue for.